# Visual studio sees dependencies in one project but not another in the same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, nuget

I have a Visual Studio solution with 2 similar projects. In one project all the dependencies are working fine and the referenced objects are found no problem. In the other project, I copied the packages.config file contents and see all the same references in the References section however I have errors on the same "using" declarations that are found without issues in the other project. How can this be? I'm constantly running into silly issues like this with Nuget. If the 2 projects have identical packages.config and identical references showing up in Visual Studio, how can there possibly be an issue here? If I right click on References and click manage Nuget packages, I see all the same references installed so I don't see how they are not found in one of the projects.

Comment: Are you targeting the same .NET Framework version in both projects?

Comment: They weren't, I changed them to be the same and it was still giving me errors but this time I was able to use the "quick fix" option to import and reference the objects I wanted. No text was changed or added to the source file so I'm not sure why I had to do that but the quick fix option did clear up the errors.